# How to bind a singleton bean in weld + jersey + javaSE

Tags: jersey, embedded-jetty, weld

My app needs to register with another app. The registration status needs to be available on a REST resource. How to bind/register a singleton object in weld? The registration process has to happen irrespective of whether the status endpoint is invoked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to register a initialized bean, I'm now initializing (registering) after the bean is loaded. Using weld callback I could achive it. Inversion of control after all ;). More Info: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_cdi_se_module